# How to setup Let's Encrypt's certificate in AWS Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a `apache` server running on amazon `linux 2`. I have installed `SSL/TLS` using Lets Encrypt and certbot. Now, my website is properly running on `https`. Now, I want the `CDN` service of cloudfront. When I tried to create a load balancer it requires a `SSL/TLS` certificate. In this case, can I provide my certbot certificate in load balancer? If yes, then in which directory my certificate lies in `apache`?

Comment: By CDN, you mean CloudFront? You don't need load balancer for that, if you already have https running on your instance.

Comment: I cannot create cloudfront distribution without SSL certificate though I have installed TLS by Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 3):

> can I provide my certbot certificate in load balancer?

Yes, but AWS provides own certificates which is more convenient than let's encrypt (at my opinion).
Anyway you need to use AWS certificate manager to register AWS certificate or your own RapidSSL, Let's Encrypt, etc... certificate.
If you want to register own certificate you must to provide 1. server secret key, 2. certificate, 3. certificate chain.

> If yes, then in which directory my certificate lies in apache?

Run

```
grep -R "SSLCertificateFile" /etc/{APACHE_FOLDER}/conf.d/*
grep -R "SSLCertificateKeyFile" /etc/{APACHE_FOLDER}/conf.d/*
grep -R "SSLCertificateChainFile" /etc/{APACHE_FOLDER}/conf.d/*
```

Where `{APACHE_FOLDER}` is `apache2` or `httpd`

Comment: Actually, I prefer Let's Encrypt's SSL/TLS because it is free. Can I use amazon's SSL certificate in free?

Comment: AWS Certificates are actually Free

Comment: @VenkatCh but the ACM certificates only apply if you buy their load balancer which costs 18$/month minimum

Comment: and ACM certificates are only free if you DON'T want access to the private key. If you want end-to-end https, or off-AWS resources protected by https you need to be in control of your private key.

Answer (score 0):

When installing your certificate inside your Amazon Linux 2 instance, you only made it available for that specific instance.
You need to either import your current certificate or request a new one in [AWS ACM](https://console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home?region=us-east-1#/).
Then you will have that certificate available for all services (including the load balancer you want) in the same AWS Region.

Comment: So, How can I import the current certificate?